# Jackson: get a null reference on deserializing

Tags: java, spring, jackson

I'm using spring-mvc for a `restful` service. By adding the dependency, my rest controllers automatically `generate json` from my `response entities`.

**Dependency**

```
jackson = '2.9.0'
compile "com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:$jackson"
```

**Objects**

```
@Getter @Setter
public final class UserDTO {
    [...]

    private int id;
    private Set<ActivityDTO> activities = Sets.newHashSet();
}


@Getter @Setter
public final class ActivityDTO {
    [...]

    private int id;
    private Set<ActivityDTO> subActivities;
}
```

**Problem**

Problems come in `special cases`. For example, I want to add an `activity` to an `user`. The following user-json `works` good, `Jackson converts it without error.`

```
{
"id": 1,
  "activities": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "subActivities": null,
    }
  ]
}
```

But if I add an activity with sub activities, it crashes!

```
{
  "id": 6,
  "activities": [
    {
      "id": 19,
      "subActivities": [
        {
          "id": 20,
          "subActivities": [
            {
              "id": 24,
              "subActivities": null
            },
            {
              "id": 21,
              "subActivities": [
                {
                  "id": 23,
                  "subActivities": null
                },
                {
                  "id": 22,
                  "subActivities": null
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ],
    }
  ]
}
```

Indeed, jackson `can't deserialize` this json and I don't understand why. I get the following error.. Any idea?

```
13:45:56.890 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod - Failed to resolve argument 0 of type 'com.ortec.gta.database.model.dto.UserDTO'
org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: JSON parse error: (was java.lang.NullPointerException); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: (was java.lang.NullPointerException) (through reference chain: com.ortec.gta.database.model.dto.UserDTO["activities"]->java.util.HashSet[2]->com.ortec.gta.database.model.dto.ActivityDTO["subActivities"]->java.util.HashSet[0]->com.ortec.gta.database.model.dto.ActivityDTO["subActivities"])
    at org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.readJavaType(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:238)
    at org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.read(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:223)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodArgumentResolver.readWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodArgumentResolver.java:201)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.readWithMessageConverters(RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.java:150)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.resolveArgument(RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.java:128)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.resolveArgument(HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:121)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.getMethodArgumentValues(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:158)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:128)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:97)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:967)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:901)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPut(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:664)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:154)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.authentication.OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:176)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:110)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:57)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:50)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:262)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at com.ortec.gta.configuration.ServletInitializer$CorsFilter.doFilter(ServletInitializer.java:78)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:262)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:478)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:80)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:624)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:799)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1455)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: (was java.lang.NullPointerException) (through reference chain: com.ortec.gta.database.model.dto.UserDTO["activities"]->java.util.HashSet[2]->com.ortec.gta.database.model.dto.ActivityDTO["subActivities"]->java.util.HashSet[0]->com.ortec.gta.database.model.dto.ActivityDTO["subActivities"])
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException.wrapWithPath(JsonMappingException.java:391)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException.wrapWithPath(JsonMappingException.java:351)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerBase.wrapAndThrow(BeanDeserializerBase.java:1689)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserializeFromObject(BeanDeserializer.java:370)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:159)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.CollectionDeserializer.deserialize(CollectionDeserializer.java:285)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.CollectionDeserializer.deserialize(CollectionDeserializer.java:244)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.CollectionDeserializer.deserialize(CollectionDeserializer.java:27)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.impl.MethodProperty.deserializeAndSet(MethodProperty.java:127)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserializeFromObject(BeanDeserializer.java:368)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:159)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.CollectionDeserializer.deserialize(CollectionDeserializer.java:285)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.CollectionDeserializer.deserialize(CollectionDeserializer.java:244)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.CollectionDeserializer.deserialize(CollectionDeserializer.java:27)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.impl.MethodProperty.deserializeAndSet(MethodProperty.java:127)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserializeFromObject(BeanDeserializer.java:368)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:159)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:4001)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:3072)
    at org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.readJavaType(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:235)
    ... 77 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.CollectionDeserializer.deserialize(CollectionDeserializer.java:271)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.CollectionDeserializer.deserialize(CollectionDeserializer.java:244)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.CollectionDeserializer.deserialize(CollectionDeserializer.java:27)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.impl.MethodProperty.deserializeAndSet(MethodProperty.java:127)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserializeFromObject(BeanDeserializer.java:368)
    ... 93 common frames omitted
```

Here the objects with all fields, maybe related to my error?

```
@Getter @Setter
public final class ActivityDTO {
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private long creationDate;
    private long modificationDate;
    private long deletionDate;
    @JsonIgnoreProperties(value = {"activities"})
    private UserDTO lastEditor;
    @JsonIgnoreProperties(value = {"subActivities", "users", "parentActivity"})
    private ActivityDTO parentActivity;
    @JsonIgnoreProperties(value = {"parentActivity"})
    private Set<ActivityDTO> subActivities;
    @JsonIgnoreProperties(value = {"activities"})
    private Set<UserDTO> users;
    private String code;
    private boolean active;
}

@Getter @Setter
public final class UserDTO {
    private int id;
    private String username;
    private String name;
    private String lastname;
    private byte[] avatar;
    private String email;
    @JsonIgnoreProperties(value = {"activities", "activities"})
    private UserDTO superior;
    private Set<RoleDTO> roles;
    @JsonIgnoreProperties(value = {"users", "parentActivity"})
    private Set<ActivityDTO> activities;
}

@Getter @Setter
public final class RoleDTO {
    private Integer id;
    private String name;
}
```

Comment: Your problem is not reproducible with given classes and json. It is indeed falling on that ',' and works fine without it.

Comment: it doesn't  for me...

Comment: @chimmi edited my subject with full objects

Comment: @Bean
    public ObjectMapper objectMapper() {
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        return objectMapper;
    }

add thi bean  to your config file and  add 
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown=true)
to your pojo classes;

Comment: @boukobbaadil lemme try ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, this definetely looks like a bug in Jackson since error only appears in version `2.8.0` and later.

As to the source of the error, it appears that the reason for it is your configuration for `ActivityDTO`, specifically this annotation:

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(value = {"parentActivity"})
private Set<ActivityDTO> subActivities;
```

So you have 3 options:

1. Rollback to Jackson 2.7.9
2. Make custom deserializer for this case
3. Remove this annotation and use custom serializer (if needed)

Comment: Rollback to 2.7.9 fixed all :) Thanks a lot

Comment: You are welcome, dont forget to update your github issue with complete POJOs, so they can reproduce it as well.

Comment: aha yes, I linked this topic just now!

Answer (score 1):

When I found this error it was because I was using primitive types as you

Try using nullable properties instead

```
@Getter @Setter    
public final class ActivityDTO {
    private Integer id;
    private String name;
    private Long creationDate;
    private Long modificationDate;
    private Long deletionDate;
```

Answer (score 0):

It is because you have an extra "," character, which makes your json invalid. It's towards the end of your json : `],`. Remove the "," and it should work.

Comment: lemme try it now

Comment: I took the JSON from your post. I used an online formatter such as https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/ 
In its current shape, it throws a parsing error (so I expect it is normal to see the error that you're seeing). If I remove the ",", then it parses OK.

Can you please make sure you're deleting the correct ","? (fourth non-whitespace char from the end of your JSON). Also, the error remains the same, or changes?

Comment: I edited my json for remove extra data, the original json has no problem; https://gist.github.com/Romain-P/d4e81ee1d272b7f56ba7db6c730c7b4b

Answer (score 0):

```
@Bean
    public ObjectMapper objectMapper() {
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        return objectMapper;
    }
```

add this bean  to your config file and  add

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown=true)
```

to your pojo classes;

Comment: It didn't fix the problem.. + if jackson is imported in dependecies, spring automatically create the ObjectMapper + some configuration. Your annotation did not help too! Thanks anyway

Comment: what if that pojo class is coming from third party library and worst if its not POJO?

Comment: what if that pojo is from third party library and we cannot add `JsonIgnoreProperties` annotation to that?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's a bug in Jackson. In my case, adding `allowSetters = true` on `@JsonIgnoreProperties` on all the cascaded classes using the annotation helped fix this issue.